# What does the solution to the transport equation describe?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm studying the transport equation

$$u_t + cu_x = 0$$

Where c is a constant.

What does the solution, $u(x,t)$,
describe?  Is it ... the height of the wave?  The location of the wave?  Does the transport equation *only* describe waves?

The source that I am studying from only says, "the wave, u(x,t) ... "

I know in the heat equation, the solution $u$ is temperature (dependent on position x and time t) and in the wave equation, the solution $u$ gives the height of the wave.

So, I'm just not sure of what the solution to the transport equation describes.

Thanks,

Comment: I thought that, at position $x$, time $t$, the solution $u(x,t)$ gives the concentration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quantity $u(x,t)$ can describe:

1. The height of a wave at point $x$ at time $t$
2. The temperature at point $x$ at time $t$
3. The concentration of some substance at point $x$ at time $t$
4. The number of cars on a 50-meter stretch of a road...

PDEs are not tied to physical *quantities*; they describe physical *processes*. The PDE $u_t+cu_x$ describes the process of propagation (*of whatever*) with constant velocity.  The PDE $u_t = ku_{xx}$ describes the process of diffusion, *of whatever* is able to diffuse. It is not really correct to say that "in $u_t =k u_{xx}$, the function $u$ is temperature". It could be that, or it could be radioactivity level, etc. Conversely, the temperature could be modeled by $u_t=ku_{xx}$, or by $u_t = cu_x$, or by $u_t = cu_x + ku_{xx}$, or by many other equations. It depends on what processes  one chooses to focus on.

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks so much @sandwich :)